# Which is the correct order to generate WAM code for L0 program terms?

Tags: prolog, warren-abstract-machine

In [Hassan Aït-Kaci's "Warren's Abstract Machine: A Tutorial Reconstruction"](http://wambook.sourceforge.net/) Section 2.2, the orders for compilation of L0 queries are clear enough: registers must be allocated with left-to-right breadth-first search and code must be generated with left-to-right post-order depth-first search.

In Section 2.3, the order for register allocation (of L0 programs) is clear: left-to-right breadth-first search. The order for code generation isn't. With the only example given, I can't tell if I should use BFS or DFS to generate code.

Can someone give me the WAM code for the following L0 program?

p(q(r(a)),s(b)).

Comment: Please look at [this recommendation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14536068/772868)!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put your program in `sample.pl`:

```
$ cat sample.pl
p(q(r(a)),s(b)).
```

Using [GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/), I then did:

```
$ gplc -w sample.pl
```

The following **WAM** instructions are then contained in `sample.wbc`:

```
clause(p(q(r(a)),s(b)),[
    get_structure(q/1,0),
    unify_structure(r/1),
    unify_atom(a),
    get_structure(s/1,1),
    unify_atom(b),
    proceed]).
```

Comment: What is the difference to `glpc -W`, which I rather use to get `.wam`-files?